# Exception of internal blocks will be catch by main try-catch but i need to raise them

Tags: java, nested-exceptions

When this code raise `NotFoundException` the exception of main block will be raised, but I would like to raise `NotFoundException`, how can I manage it?

```
try {
    if (x > y) {
        throw new NotFoundException("entity is not found");
    }
} catch (final Exception e) {
    throw new InternalServerErrorException(e);
}
```

Comment: Ideally you should write your code in such a way which enumerates all the possible exception types, and then you would not have this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
try {
    if (x>y)
        throw new NotFoundException("entity is not found");
} catch (Exception e) {
    if (e instanceof NotFoundException) {
        throw e;
    } else {
        throw new InternalServerErrorException(e);
    }
}
```

or...

```
try {
    if (x>y)
        throw new NotFoundException("entity is not found");
} catch (NotFoundException e) {
    throw e;
} catch (Exception e) {
    throw new InternalServerErrorException(e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing here is that you don't need the try catch block. You could just use

```
if (x > y) {
    throw new NotFoundException("entity is not found");
}
```

Obviously the inner exception in your code will be caught in the try catch block so rather than catching `Exception` in your catch block, You can catch some more specific Exception. For example if a block of code is expected to throw `IOException`, rather than catching `Exception` you should catch `IOException`